# Reading excel file with line breaks and tabs preserved using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlrd

I am trying to read excel file cells having multi line text in it. I am using xlrd 1.2.0. But when I print or even write the text in cell to `.txt` file it doesn't preserve line breaks or tabs i.e `\n or \t`.

**Input:**

[image]

**File URL:**
[Excel file](https://a.uguu.se/SWkpNIxGf28n_16.xlsx)

**Code:**

```
import xlrd
filenamedotxlsx = '16.xlsx'
gall_artists = xlrd.open_workbook(filenamedotxlsx)
sheet = gall_artists.sheet_by_index(0)
bio = sheet.cell_value(0,1)
print(bio)
```

**Output:**

```
"Biography 2018-2019 Manoeuvre Textiles Atelier, Gent, Belgium 2017-2018 Thalielab, Brussels, Belgium 2017 Laboratoires d'Aubervilliers, Paris 2014-2015 Galveston Artist Residency (GAR), Texas 2014 MACBA, Barcelona & L'appartment 22, Morocco - Residency 2013 International Residence Recollets, Paris 2007 Gulbenkian & RSA Residency, BBC Natural History Dept, UK 2004-2006 Delfina Studios, UK Studio Award, London 1998-2000 De Ateliers, Post-grad Residency, Amsterdam 1995-1998 BA (Hons) Textile Art, Winchester School of Art UK "
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1975 Born in Hangzhou, Zhejiang, China
1980 Started to learn Chinese ink painting
2000 BA, Major in Oil Painting, China Academy of Art, Hangzhou, China
Curator, Hangzhou group exhibition for 6 female artists Untitled, 2000 Present
2007 MA, New Media, China Academy of Art, Hangzhou, China, studied under Jiao Jian
Lecturer, Department of Art, Zhejiang University, Hangzhou, China
2015 PhD, Calligraphy, China Academy of Art, Hangzhou, China, studied under Wang Dongling
Jury, 25th National Photographic Art Exhibition, China Millennium Monument, Beijing, China
2016 Guest professor, Faculty of Humanities, Zhejiang University, Hangzhou, China
Associate professor, Research Centre of Modern Calligraphy, China Academy of Art, Hangzhou, China
Researcher, Lanting Calligraphy Commune, Zhejiang, China
2017 Christie's produced a video about Chu Chu's art
2018 Featured by Poetry Calligraphy Painting Quarterly No.2, Beijing, China
Present Vice Secretary, Lanting Calligraphy Society, Hangzhou, China
Vice President, Zhejiang Female Calligraphers Association, Hangzhou, China
```

I have also used `repr()` to see if there are `\n` characters or not, but there aren't any.

Comment: Can you upload the excel file again please? The link is broken.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, link is updated @dildeolupbiten

Comment: The output seems as you expected, there are `\n` escape sequence characters at the end of the lines.

Comment: @dildeolupbiten see this, I have also tried writing to .txt file same results. https://imgur.com/aFyc8Ks

Comment: Here, the results are different when I run your codes: https://i.hizliresim.com/1pEJBb.jpg

Comment: Pls try on other rows, for that same column

Comment: I guess some parts of the text is too long, that's why they appear as a paragraph. However some parts of the text is printed line by line because of their relatively short length.

Comment: there is pattern in new line, every line starts with year i,e `2015-6` , So I don't think it is something with length.

Comment: `1968    Joined the Antiquities Department of the National Palace Museum, special
izing in ancient bronze vessels` <-- This is the long text that I mentioned. The character limit of cmd is 80 characters and this text obviously has more characters than 80.

Comment: ah okay, I got that, but there is no point text being in txt file in single paragraph

Comment: When we write some codes without pressing `<enter>`, what we have written will be considered as the 1'st line, even though the text continues in the 2'nd line because of it's length.